# Non-exhaustive patterns error when trying to find the first different character in two strings

Tags: haskell, recursion, match

I want to write a `match :: String -> String -> Maybe Char` function that should return the first string's different character (e.g. `Just 'b'`). If both strings are identical or the first string is the second string's prefix, the function should return `Nothing`.

So far, I have this code:

```
match :: String -> String -> Maybe Char
match [] [] = Nothing
match [x] [] = Just x
match [] [y] = Nothing
match [x] [y]
  | x == y = Nothing 
  | otherwise = Just x
match (x:xs) (y:ys)
  | x == y = match xs ys
  | otherwise = Just x
```

Which returns the correct value for, let's say `match "apple" "aple" == Just 'p'`, but for the case below, I get a `Non-exhaustive patterns` error, which is strange becuase I thought I've covered every case:

```
*main> match (replicate 21 'a') (repeat 'a')
*** Exception: match.hs:(64,1)-(72,22): Non-exhaustive patterns in function match
```

Comment: You did not implement patterns for `match [] (_:_:_)` and `match (_:_:_) []`

Comment: Keep warnings on with `-Wall` to make GHC report the missing cases at compile time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Matching with a singleton list (`[x]`, a list with *exactly* one element) here is not necessary. You can work with the empty list `[]` and the "cons" `(x:xs)`:

```
match :: String -> String -> Maybe Char
match [] _ = Nothing
match (x:_) [] = Just x
match (x:xs) (y:ys)
  | x == y = match xs ys
  | otherwise = Just x
```